# WP7 LINQ Delete not working - Getting NullReferenceException

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7

I'm working on a WP7 app where i need to delete a row using the DeleteOnSubmit() method, but i keep getting a NullReferenceException error. I can't find where the issue is.

```
public void HardDeleteOrder(int deleteOrderId)
{

    var oResult = from o in App.orderDataContext.orders
              where o.OrderId == deleteOrderId
              select o;


    foreach (var oRow in oResult)
    {
       App.orderDataContext.Orders.DeleteOnSubmit(oRow);
    }
    App.orderDataContext.SubmitChanges();
}
```

When i run this, the code crashes on the ending brace of the method with an exception message "NullReferenceException was unhandled".

Here's the Stack trace:

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
Message=NullReferenceException
StackTrace:
   at System.Data.Linq.Mapping.MetaAccessor`2.SetBoxedValue(Object& instance, Object value)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.ClearForeignKeysHelper(MetaAssociation assoc, Object trackedInstance)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.ClearForeignKeyReferences(TrackedObject to)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.PostProcessUpdates(List`1 insertedItems, List`1 deletedItems)
   at System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode)
   at System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges()
   at orders.viewmodels.OrderViewModel.HardDeleteOrder(Int32 deleteOrderId)
   at orders.OrderView.RemoveOrderFromDatabase()
   at orders.OrderView.RemoveOrder()
   at orders.OrderView.detailsBarCancel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at orders.App.detailsBarCancel_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarItemContainer.FireEventHandler(EventHandler handler, Object sender, EventArgs args)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButton.ClickEvent()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBarIconButtonContainer.ClickEvent()
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ApplicationBar.OnCommand(UInt32 idCommand)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Shell.Interop.NativeCallbackInteropWrapper.OnCommand(UInt32 idCommand)
```

What am I missing here ?

Answer (score 0):

This is mostly due to foreign key constraint.
According to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386925.aspx

> LINQ to SQL does not support or recognize cascade-delete operations. If you want to delete a row in a table that has constraints against it, you must complete either of the following tasks:

```
Set the ON DELETE CASCADE rule in the foreign-key constraint in the database.

Use your own code to first delete the child objects that prevent the parent object from being deleted.
```